# rsync not accuratenly syncing large postgres dump (~30GB)

Tags: linux, postgresql, rsync

I have a large postgres dump file (~30GB) which is being rsynced (between two Ubuntu machines, both using rsync 3.1.1, protocol v31).

I'm finding that the synced file matches the correct file size but does not match an MD5 check.

Is there any reason for this? Does the rsync delta algorithm not work correctly on a very large file in the neighbourhood of 30GB? The problem seems to have started once the file turned a corner in somewhere in the low to mid 20GBs.

```
/usr/bin/rsync -av -e "ssh -l username -p 22" "192.168.1.50:/data/backups/" "/data/backups"
```

I've also turned off the delta feature on rsync (with -W), so the current command is

```
/usr/bin/rsync -avW -e "ssh -l username -p 22" "192.168.1.50:/data/backups/" "/data/backups"
```

Comment: 30GB isn't stunningly large. Please add the actual command you use to copy the file(s) to your question. Obfuscate if you must but make sure it's otherwise identical.

Comment: @roaima I've updated the OP with that information.

Comment: Hmm. Nothing obviously wrong with that, except we can apply some optimisations to make it easier to read. This is the same as your top command: `/usr/bin/rsync -av username@192.168.1.50:"/data/backups/" "/data/backups"`. Does the source change while `rsync` is running? Does the source content change after it's been created, but in such a fashion that the timestamp and size remains untouched?

Comment: The source only changes at one predetermined time every day, well away from when I'm trying the rsync. I've now also verified that the same thing happens with scp and sftp, the size is preserved, but the md5sum changes.

Comment: What about the file modification time? Does that get preserved too when the file content is updated?

Comment: @roaima yes, the modification time is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` uses a file's timestamp and size as a shortcut to decide whether or not it needs to be transferred. If you update a file's content but manage to keep the size and time unchanged then the file will be skipped by `rsync`.

The most efficient solution is to help `rsync` by updating a file's modification time when it is modified.

Otherwise you need to tell `rsync` either to ignore the shortcut and just copy the file

```
rsync --whole-file -av username@192.168.1.50:"/data/backups/" "/data/backups"
```

or to perform a full checksum to see if the file has changed

```
rsync --checksum -av username@192.168.1.50:"/data/backups/" "/data/backups"
```

Which of these two options you choose is dependent on network speed vs processor speed.